# magento 2 addtocart.phtml template file can not override

Tags: magento-2.1, template, overrides

I need little help,I am trying to override `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml` but no luck

**I am using Magento 2.1 version**.

I tried below code in my module
**file location**: `Myvendor1_Module1/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

Layout file: **catalog_product_view**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
           <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Myvendor1_Module1::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
           </action>
       </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

I already cleared cache, generation folder and as well as flush cache but it cannot override `addtocart.phtml` template file.

**Edit**: My module is fine working and it is enabled.
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out in

> Myvendor1_Module1/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="Myvendor1_Module1::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>  
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Magento 2.1.17 - Override product option select.phtml file.(Not block file only phtml file) Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To override **addtocart.phtml** template file in your module use below code

**1.** Create file `catalog_product_view.xml` in the directory path
 `Vendor_Module/view/frontend/layout` and add below code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>        
            <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="Vendor_Module::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>  
        </body>
    </page>
```